# Delete all the rows in between two rows which has particular words

Tags: excel, vba

We are having numerous excel sheets with almost 40,000 records pertaining to geological data. Within that excel, the last parameter (Criteria) for a data will be "Color Table:".

Like:

```
Row 35  Color Table: (RGB with entries)
Row 36  0: 255,255,255,255
Row 37  1: 19,91,19,255
..
..
..
Row 58 **Files:** W:\01 GIS\AP_GSI_Map Survey_1  (***Starting of next data***)
```

From Row 59 onwards the next parameter for the next data will start....and again,

```
Row 88  Colour Table: (2 Entries)
Row 89 0: 1,56,76
..
..
..
Row 102 Files: XXXXX
```

So, my question is: How to delete all the rows which falls between row which has the text: `Color Table` & the row which has the text `Files:` in it ?

Knew a bit of basics in VBA. But don't know how to proceed with this.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't test it yet, but I think that this should work:

```
Dim FoundCellColor As Range
Dim FoundCellFiles As Range
Dim colorArray (0) As Integer
Dim fileArray (0) As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim k As Integer

i = 0

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Set your range here, placeholder A:A
Set FoundCellColor = Range("A:A").Find(what:="Color Table")
Set FoundCellFiles = Range("A:A").Find(what:="Files")

Do Until FoundCellColor Is Nothing
    Redim Preserve colorArray(i)
    Redim Preserve fileArray(i)

    colorRow = FoundCellColor.Row
    fileRow = FoundCellFiles.Row

    colorArray(i) = colorRow
    fileArray(i) = fileRow

    Set FoundCellColor = Range("A:A").FindNext
    Set FoundCellFiles = Range("A:A").FindNext

    i = i + 1
Loop

For k = 0 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count

    If UBound(Filter(colorArray, k)) < 0 AND UBound(Filter(fileArray, k)) < 0 Then ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Rows(k).Delete

Next
```

Note: I assume that every "Color Table" has a corresponding "Files" section. If that should not be the case, you'll have to adjust the code accordingly.

Comment: Thanka mate. But it show's Syntax Error at this point

ReDim Preserve colorArray(i)
ReDim fileArray colorArray(j)

I don't even have a clue of what this colorArray will do. Isn't it something to do with color values. May i know why we are using this ?

Comment: The color array will store the row number when your "Color Table" string occurs. Same goes for the file array. In the end you delete every row that is not in one of these arrays. The result should be what you've requested. I fixed two typos in the code, might work now. I'll test it myself later